# Running arm64 windows binaries on arm64 Raspberry Pi

Tags: windows, arm

I am interested in running [the arm64 binary of Teams for Windows](https://office365itpros.com/2020/10/16/native-arm64-version-of-teams-available/) on the Raspberry pi 4 8gb arm64, at the moment I am using Ubuntu 21.04. There is a version of [teams for linux](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/releases) running on the Raspberry Pi, but I think it is not that efficiant. Of cause wine can be used, but there are hardly any binaries for i386 for windows and I suggest it is not that efficiant (It needs a lot of ressources).  So wheather there is a binary with a fitting architecture, it might be a good idea to use it. Maybe someone has a good idea.

P.s: I am a little bit affraid of installing Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi, because I think it might be allegal to [download Windows 10 from
this side.](https://uup.rg-adguard.net/).

Comment: If you have lost your original login credentials, please see *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)*.   Until you can access this account, there is no point in leaving the question open.  If you regain access, please leave a comment here @goldilocks and I will re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

> wheather there is a binary with a fitting architecture, it might be a good idea to use it.

If you mean, can I run a compiled-for-windows binary on linux without the use of an emulator like WINE or a container running an actual windows instance, the answer is generally no.  It is certainly no in this case.  TeamViewer is a network app and the networking API and ABI is incompatible.